# how to split vertically for the chosen buffer when using :ls

Tags: vim

I know after using `:ls`, I can do `:3sb` to open the 3rd buffer in a horizontally split window. How to open it in a *new* vertical window?

I tried `:3vb` or `:vs 3b` or `:vert 3b` etc. none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `:vert 3sb`, that is the very same command prepended by `vert`.

Alternatively, you can open split as usual (`:3sb`) and then move it with <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> followed by H/J/K/L (don't be confused with h/j/k/l: small letters move cursor between windows, while big letters move window itself).